# How much power does Apple TV use on standby?

Tags: appletv, power

I just bought a third-gen Apple TV, and I don't want to have to open Settings to put it to sleep every time I'm done using it. It seems it won't fall asleep automatically for quite some time, so I'd like to know how much power it draws when not in use.

Comment: You can configure the time to auto-sleep with Settings > General > Sleep after, which ranges from 15 minutes to 10 hours, or never. You can also manually put it to sleep by holding the play/pause button while a home screen icon is selected. (This only works when selecting the "app" icons, not the large content images on top.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [review](http://www.flatpanelshd.com/review.php?subaction=showfull&id=1332241339) on FlatpanelsHD.com, it will use **0.8 watts** when in standby (not sleep), and 1.9 watts when in use. To use their description, this is "ridiculously low."

Since all the device needs to do is wait for Bonjour, AirPlay, or IR signals — and the upper number matches up with [Apple's own report](http://images.apple.com/environment/reports/docs/AppleTV_Product_Environmental_Report_2012.pdf) — I'd say this is believable.

*Fun perspective fact from the Apple report: It takes 30 Apple TVs, all streaming HD video, to use the same amount of power as a common 60W light bulb.*

You can quickly put the Apple TV to sleep by holding the play/pause button on the home screen. The cursor should be over one of the apps, not a content preview, and last I tested, this didn't work with the play/pause button of the Remote app.

Comment: This applies to the second generation, which I'm assuming is similar enough to the third generation. I may, of course, be wrong.

Comment: I didn't know that! That's actually pretty impressive.